Xcode 16.2 error: 'Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code' React Native iOS
I recently upgraded my app's react native version from 0.72.3 to 0.76.5, made changes carefully by getting help from react native upgrade helper. Everything was running smoothly, were able to build the application using Xcode 16.2 (macOS Sonoma 14.5) or command line. Somehow, it stopped building throwing an error at build time saying:

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

package.json
{
  "name": "MYAPP",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@bam.tech/react-native-image-resizer": "^3.0.10",
    "@m-c2/ripple": "^1.0.7",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.3",
    "@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^10.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^21.6.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^21.6.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.5.0",
    "@tanstack/query-async-storage-persister": "^5.4.3",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.12.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query-persist-client": "^5.4.3",
    "@types/react-native-check-box": "^2.1.6",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^5.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-react-native": "^6.2.0",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-intl": "^6.4.7",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1302.0",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.3.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.13.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.2",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-page-indicator": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-popover-view": "^6.0.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.3.12",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.27",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.25.0",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.10.1",
    "react-native-switch-with-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.6",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "react-redux": "^9.2.0",
    "react-router-native": "^6.15.0",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.25.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.76.5",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.76.5",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.197",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.32.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.4"
}

Podfile
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'MYAPP' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  # Firebase pods
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true

  # PhotoLibrary pod
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary"

  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'

  target 'MYAPPTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false,
      # :ccache_enabled => true
    )
  end
end

I already tried reinstalling node dependencies and pods, by removing node_modules folder and by cleaning Xcode build, pods folder and lock file. Nothing worked 
Used these commands:

rm -rf node_modules
npm install
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
cd ios && pod install | bundle exec pod install

Any help in fixing this issue will be much appreciated, thanks in advance 
